# Dart app cannot find index.bootstrap.initialize.dart

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I am uncertain why, on attempting to start my app I get the following errors:

### debug

```
GET http://localhost:63342/epimss_polymer_app/web/index.bootstrap.initialize.dart
```

### pub_serve

```
Build error:
Transform Reflectable on epimss_polymer_app|ReflectableTransformed threw error: The null object does not have a getter 'type'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'type'
Receiver: null
Arguments: []
dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart 42                          Object._noSuchMethod
dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart 45                          Object.noSuchMethod
package:reflectable/src/transformer_implementation.dart 2397  _Capabilities._supportsMeta.<fn>
...

Build completed with 1 errors.
[web] GET index.bootstrap.initialize.dart => Could not find asset epimss_polymer_app|web/index.bootstrap.initialize.dart.
```

### pubspec

```
name: 'epimss_polymer_app'
version: 0.1.0
description: A web app built using polymer.dart.
#author:
#homepage: https://www.example.com

environment:
  sdk: '>=1.9.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  analyzer: 0.27.1
  autonotify_observe: 1.0.0+7

  browser: 0.10.0+2
  bwu_fontawesome_iconset_svg: 0.3.0-3

  epimss_polymer_clerking:
    path: ../epimss_polymer_clerking
  epimss_polymer_reg:
    path: ../epimss_polymer_reg

  polymer: 1.0.0-rc.15
  polymer_elements: 1.0.0-rc.8
  polymer_interop: 1.0.0-rc.8

  quiver_collection: 1.0.0

  shared:
    path: ../../../../dart/shared/shared

  web_components: 0.12.2+2

dependency_overrides:
  reflectable: ^0.5.1

dev_dependencies:
  test: 0.12.6+2

transformers:
- autonotify_observe
- web_components:
    entry_points: web/index.html
- reflectable:
    entry_points: web/index.bootstrap.initialize.dart
- $dart2js:
    $include: '**/*.bootstrap.initialize.dart'
    minify: true
    commandLineOptions:
    - --trust-type-annotations
    - --trust-primitives
```

I am using the current Dart SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the newest Polymer version try

```yaml
transformers:
- autonotify_observe
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
```

instead of

```yaml
transformers:
- autonotify_observe
- web_components:
    entry_points: web/index.html
- reflectable:
    entry_points: web/index.bootstrap.initialize.dart
```

Comment: Thanks for your help as usual.

Comment: I'm unable to add autonotify_observe dependency:

`Package autonotify_observe has no versions that match >=1.0.0+7 <2.0.0 derived from:
- writingtutor depends on version ^1.0.0+7`

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: The error message is misleading. This only means that `pub get` can't find a matching set of dependencies. Some dependencies don't have compatible version ranges withing the specified contraints. This is hard and cumbersome to debug (known issue). I'd start to comment out all other dependencies and then try different combination to find the smallest set of dependencies that cause resolution to fail. What's also important to note is, that the dependencies also need to be compatible with the installed SDK version and the SDK version range specified in `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank you for the tip. I found the issue with `observe` package. After removing this dependency, `autonotify_observe` was successfully added.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Found out that this dependency conflict issue stems from the fact that `autonotify_observe` uses a modified `observe` package as documented here https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/autonotify_observe at the bottom of the page.