# Polymer-dart: http://www.xxx/index.bootstrap.initialize.dart Failed to load resource - where is it?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a Dart (1_16_0_dev_2) Polymer web app. I see [>the problem here<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954862/dart-app-cannot-find-index-bootstrap-initialize-dart) , but I still have it. My yaml is :

```
dependencies:
  browser: ^0.10.0
  polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.16
  polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.8

transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
      - web/index.html
- $dart2js:
    $include: '**/*.bootstrap.initialize.dart' (I've tried with and without this line)
    minify: true
    commandLineOptions:
    - --trust-type-annotations
    - --trust-primitives
```

I've tried without the dart2js too. I can view my website in (some!?) Chromes on different devices, but Dartium gives this complaint

```
http://www.xxx/index.bootstrap.initialize.dart Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

(and I assume it's why FireFox and Edge show a blank page).

What am I doing wrong please?
Thanks,
cheers,
s

Comment: I run into this as well frequently. I couldn't pin it down. Usually killing `pub serve` (for example using the `stop` button in the `Pub Serve` view in WebStorm` fixes the issue. Often `pub serve` also prints syntax errors when the application is loaded from a freshly started `pub serve` which it doesn't print when the application is just reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing:

```
<script src="packages/web_components/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
```

in index.html.  Now it works in Firefox, and Dartium isn't looking for the bootstrap file.